# Dynamic validation in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have model, where car property is optional, but there is some property in car nested document, which should be required if User has car, like `cartype : {required: true}`, but when car is defined.

```
 var UserSchema = new Schema({
        email: {
            type: 'String',
            required: true
        },
        car: {
            carType: {
               // should be required if user have car
               type: 'Number',
               default: TransportType.Car
            },
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `default` value for `carType`, we can define one function `hasCar` to `required` of `carType` as below

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: 'String',
        required: true
    },
    car: { 
        carType: {
           type: 'Number',
           required: hasCar,
           //default: TransportType.Car
        },
    }
});

function hasCar() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.car) !== JSON.stringify({});//this.car; && Object.keys(this.car).length > 0;
}
```

With test codes

```
var u1 = new UUU({
    email: 'test.user1@email.com'
});

u1.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('save u1 successfully');
});

var u2 = new UUU({
    email: 'test.user1@email.com',
    car: {carType: 23}
});

u2.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('save u2 successfully');
});
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56db9d21d3fb99340bcd113c"), "email" : "test.user1@email.com", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56db9d21d3fb99340bcd113d"), "email" : "test.user1@email.com", "car" : { "carType" : 23 }, "__v" : 0 }
```

---

However, if there is `default` value of `carType`, here maybe one workaround

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: 'String',
        required: true
    },
    car: { 
        carType: {
           type: 'Number',
           required: hasCar,
           default: 1
        },
    }
});

function hasCar() {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.car) === JSON.stringify({carType: 1})) {
        this.car = {};
    }
    return JSON.stringify(this.car) === JSON.stringify({});
}

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    // if there is only default value of car, just remove this default carType from car 
    if (JSON.stringify(this.car) === JSON.stringify({carType: 1})) {
        delete this.car;
    }
    next();
});
```

With the above test codes, results are

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56db9f73df8599420b7d258a"), "email" : "test.user1@email.com", "car" : null, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56db9f73df8599420b7d258b"), "email" : "test.user1@email.com", "car" : { "carType" : 23 }, "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: Thanks, required function is what I really need.